# How do I list the supported resolutions of my HDMI display/monitor?

Tags: hdmi

How do I list the supported resolutions of my HDMI display/monitor?

On the raspberrypi website, there is a complete [list of modes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) supported by raspberrypi but it does not list only the ones supported by my monitor.

Answer (score 1):

From [raspberrypi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=5851), you can use `tvservice`:

> 1. Run “tvservice -m CEA” to give a list of CEA supported modes.
> 2. Run “tvservice -m DMT” to give a list of DMT supported modes.
> 3. Run “tvservice -s” to give you the current state.
>
> Alternatively you can do the following:
>   1. Run “tvservice -d <file>” to capture a monitor’s EDID.
>   2. Pass this file to edidparser. Run “edidparser <file>”.